# Functional-reactive operator in RxJava2 that produces new state from previous state and additional inputs

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, purely-functional

I am working on a little showcase that is supposed to demonstrate how you can write interactive programs in a purely functional manner using functional-reactive programming (specifically RxJava2).

My goal is to create a simple interactive game. The main function of the game (let's call it Next Game State, or NGS for short) takes the current state of the game, a user input, as well as a random number and computes the next state of the game from those three inputs. Fairly straightforward so far. The user inputs and the random numbers are `Flowable`s that were created from `Iterable`s or via generators. I envisioned that the game state itself would be a Flowable as well (but I might be wrong about that).

I am struggling to find the right functional-reactive operator that applies the function to the three inputs and produces the next state of the game. Initially, I thought that `Flowable.zip(source1, source2, source3, zipper)` would be right operation: it could take the three flows and combine it via the NGS function into a new Flowable. That, unfortunately, does not account for the fact that the resulting Flowable itself needs to be one of the inputs of the zip operation, which seems an impossible setup. My next idea was to use `Flowable.generate`, but I need the two additional inputs from other `Flowable`s to calculate the next state, and there is no way to feed those into the `generate` operator.

In a nutshell, I'm trying to realize something similar to this (pseudo-)marble diagram:

```
  Game --------------(0)-------------(1)-----------------(2)-----------------(3)---
  State                \   _______   / \       _______   / \       _______   /
                        \_|       |_/   \_____|       |_/   \_____|       |_/
                          | Next  |           | Next  |           | Next  |
                     _____| Game  |      _____| Game  |      _____| Game  |
                    /   __| State |     /   __| State |     /   __| State |
                   /   /  '_______'    /   /  '_______'    /   /  '_______'
                  /   /               /   /               /   /
  User           /   /               /   /               /   /
  Input --------o---/---------------o---/---------------o---/--------------------
                   /                   /                   /
  Random          /                   /                   /
  Number --------o-------------------o-------------------o---------------------------
```

The top line, I admit, is somewhat non-standard, but it's my best attempt to visualize that, beginning with an initial game state `(0)`, each successive game state `(1)`, `(2)`, `(3)`, etc., is created from the previous game state plus the additional inputs.

I realize that there is probably a relatively straightforward way to do this with an `Emitter` or maybe inside a downstream subscriber, but one of the goals of this exercise is to show that this can be solved entirely without side effects or `void` methods.

So, long story short, is there an existing operator that supports this behavior? If not, what would be involved in creating one? Or is there maybe some alternative solution that uses a slightly different overall setup?

Comment: Does the game-state depend on the user-input and random numer, or is it possible, that the game-state changes by itself somehow? I would guess, that the game-state is always derived from the seed-state plus some input values. When a input value (random number, user-input) changes, a new game-state is calculated.

Comment: @HansWurst the game state is indeed always derived from a previous game state and some additional input values; the game state does not change by itself, it can only change in response to a user input

Comment: Do you need the user-input and random-number to be processed as a pair? For example (newInput1, randomNumber1, curr_state) -> new State; (newInput2, randomNumber2, curr_state) -> new State. Or is it possible, that an input is emitted without a new random-number? For example (newInput1, randomNumber1, curr_state) -> new State; (newInput2, randomNumber1, curr_state) -> new State. This examples display, that a the input is always combined with the latest values for random-number (combineLatest/ withLatestFrom).

Comment: @HansWurst Yes, user input and random number always come as a pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assumption

The user-input and randome number are two separate streams, which could emit at any time by their own.

### Solution

> long story short, is there an existing operator that supports this behavior?

Yes, there is. You could use `#scan(seed<T>, { current<T>, upstream<Q> -> newValue<T> }`.

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.BiFunction
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.processors.PublishProcessor
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class So65589721 {
    @Test
    fun `65589721`() {
        val userInput = PublishProcessor.create<String>()
        val randomNumber = PublishProcessor.create<Int>()

        val scan = Flowable.combineLatest(userInput, randomNumber, BiFunction<String, Int, Pair<String, Int>> { u, r ->
            u to r
        }).scan<GameState>(GameState.State1, { currentState, currentInputTuple ->
            // calculate new state from `currentState` and combined pair
            GameState.State3(currentInputTuple.first, currentInputTuple.second)
        })

        val test = scan.test()

        randomNumber.offer(42)

        userInput.offer("input1")
        userInput.offer("input2")

        test
            .assertValues(GameState.State1, GameState.State3("input1", 42), GameState.State3("input2", 42))
    }

    interface GameState {
        object State1 : GameState
        data class State3(val value: String, val random: Int) : GameState
    }
}
```

This examples shows how to use `scan` to calculate a new state from a given input pair and a current state. With `scan` you can "hold" state in a safe manner, without expsosing it to side-effects.

### Note

- the `seed-value` passed to `scan` will be emitted as first value on subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, @HansWurst. In my particular case the specific solution was a `zip` followed by a `scan`: `zip(random, responses, Input.FACTORY::create).scan(State.FACTORY.create(1, 100, Optional.empty()), instance::next)`

Comment: My complete working example (Java 8 + RxJava 2) can be found here: https://github.com/raner/top.java.purely.functional/blob/master/src/main/java/top/java/purely/functional/example/PurePlayAndInteraction.java#L52